# Python dtype('O') . Processing object data type. Converting to string/integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object-type

I have the table from ImDB with actors.

[image]

From this table I want to drop all rows where **imdb_actors.birthYear** is missing or is less than 1950 and  also drope those where **imdb_actors.deathYear** has some value.

*Idea is to get a dataset with actors who are alive and not retired.*

```
imdb_actors.birthYear.dtype
Out:dtype('O')
```

And I can't convert to string, this doesn't help: `imdb_actors['birthYear'] = imdb_actors['birthYear'].astype('|S')`. It just ruins all years.

That's why I can't execute: `imdb_actors[imdb_actors.birthYear >= 1955]`
When I try `imdb_actors.birthYear.astype(str).astype(int)` I get the message: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\N'`

What will be the way to drop missing and apply >= 1950 condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert numeric data to numeric series:

```
num_cols = ['birthYear', 'deathYear']
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Specifying `errors='coerce'` forces non-convertible elements to `NaN`.

Then create masks for your 3 conditions, combine via the vectorised `|` "or" operator, negate via `~`, and apply Boolean indexing on your dataframe:

```
m1 = df['birthYear'].isnull()
m2 = df['birthYear'] < 1950
m3 = df['deathYear'].notnull()

res = df[~(m1 | m2 | m3)]
```

Comment: df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') loses good cells with years and just gives me back each column as NaN.

Comment: I'd love to check this out, but I'm having trouble copy-pasting the image you posted on your question into my code. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the type of your birthYear serie is Object which would be for strings or a mix of types.

You will want to clean this serie first by applying a function like this :

```
imdb_actors.birthYear = imdb_actors.birthYear.map(lambda x: int(x) if str(x) != '\\N' else pd.np.nan)
```

then you can do your filtering:

```
imdb_actors[imdb_actors.birthYear >= 1955]
```

Comment: Trying to run the first line I get the error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\\N'

Comment: could you post a sample of your data ?

Comment: You should use vectorised operations. `map` + `lambda` on `object` dtype is no better than a simple loop with a `list`.

Comment: I have a great trouble converting tables to a nice format on SO. Is there a way to paste it nicely? Sorry for silly question.

Comment: @Pinkythemouse, That's a good question. See this question for answers: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).